# Vector normalization in jscience.mathematics.vector

Tags: java, vector, jscience

I have a `Vector<Real> vec` in jscience. I could not find the function to normalize it. Could you please help me to normalize `vec`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class [`org.jscience.mathematics.vector.Float64Vector`](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/vector/Float64Vector.html), a `Vector<Float64>`, includes both `norm()` and `normValue()` methods. Although a `Vector<Real>`, a collection of arbitrary precision real numbers, lacks either method, you can take the `Real#sqrt()` of the sum of the components' squares, as outlined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29).